# SQL Combine two tables in a View

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

[image: Simple Table Diagram]

I have three tables (simplified table diagram above).  From these three tables I would like to create a view that would be the combination of TableA and TableB (all rows from tableA and all from TableB with no duplicates).  The catch is I don't want the foriegn keys from TableA but instead I want the names from TableC in the view.  A row would something like below

Id, FullName_A, FullName_B

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly the following [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6cd23/2/0) example will get you what you need:

```
SELECT A.Id, C1.FullName AS APerson, C2.FullName As BPerson
FROM TableA AS A
  LEFT JOIN TableC AS C1 ON A.FK_PersonA = C1.Id
  LEFT JOIN TableC AS C2 ON A.FK_PersonB = C2.Id
UNION
SELECT B.Id, B.FullName1 AS APerson, B.FullName2 AS BPerson
FROM TableB AS B
```

Comment: I have been working on this for hours and 5 minutes after the post you solve, amazing

Comment: Actually I want all records from A and B regardless if the same Id

Comment: Actually this is not pulling all the records, I thought it was working but I just compared size of both tables and I am only getting a very small portion of the two tables.  I want all records from both tables.

Comment: I think the problem is some of the Foreign keys are null, could this cause the rows to not be pulled?

Comment: Changing the INNER join to LEFT join seemed to work for me, does this make sense?

Comment: I modified my answer to `LEFT` joins to pull the main table regardless of if they have the `PersonA` and/or `PersonB` Ids.  I also added the SQL Fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks this works and SQL Fiddle is new to me, very cool.  I will have to use it in future.  Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, in the SQL Fiddle in my answer the it compacts the unions so that only unique records are shown.  If you have the same Id in TableA and TableB but the names don't match up then it will show both copies of that Id.  This [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa237/1/0) illustrates that.